# How to edit the Recurring profiles page?

Tags: magento-1.9, recurring, customize

I like to add a button for each recurring profile to the table.
Now I don't know how to edit that page.
I can't find an Phtml file that reference to recurring profile.
The directory is: `

> app/design/frontend/rwd/my-theme/template

anyone knows how to edit the recurring profiles page in the customer panel?

Answer (score 1):

You can find the path of the recurring profiles block in `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/sales/recurring_profile.xml`

```
    <sales_recurring_profile_index>
            ...
            <reference name="my.account.wrapper">
                <block type="sales/recurring_profiles" name="sales.recurring.profiles" template="sales/recurring/profiles.phtml">
```

This template is for the profiles list page and detail page template will be the below one.

```
<sales_recurring_profile_view__tabs>
        ...
        <reference name="my.account.wrapper">
            <block type="sales/recurring_profile_view" name="sales.recurring.profile.view" template="sales/recurring/profile/view.phtml">
```

Override this templates and change the code as you wish.

Comment: I like to change table header names, how do I do that?

Comment: I don't know where it is defined.